# Most suitable database type for high score list

Tags: mysql, postgresql, nosql

I am developing an iPhone app which needs a high score system stored on a remote server.

If you are in 500th place on a list, you should see places 495 to 505 on the screen.

**EDIT (forgot to mention this): You can be in multiple lists, for example the lists "London", "Super Hero Team" and "Fiction Fans". How do I most efficiently select the 10 places around my placement in all my lists, if there are millions of users and thousands of groups?**

I thought of the following:

- One select for each list: `select * from scores where list = '$list' order by points desc limit $myplace-5, 10`
- A single select for all your lists: `select * from scores where list in ($lists) order by list, points desc` and then use PHP to pick out the right spots

With all the new database types showing up (NoSQL, etc.), is there a database type that is ideal for this problem?

For example one that inserts your score in the right place from the start so each `select` won't have to sort the data?

Or a very quick way of selecting the 10 places around your place? (The actual sorting could happen on the client side if I just got the right rows selected)

Comment: You mean you loop through entire resultset for every user? How does PHP know which user is it?

Comment: "I am afraid this is not going to scale if we get many users." Define "many". Simple queries like this run in milliseconds, even with hundreds of concurrent users. But you do need some serious hardware for your database server.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to get the exact data you need with a SQL query, instead of doing it through PHP. Using a NoSQL database is probably not a good fit for your problem. MySQL will deal with that amount of data without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the order as you wish directly with below queries

```
//user id
set @ID = 3; 

// get the score of the user
set @Score = (select score
              from users
              where ID = @ID);

//get the user who are less than you, and greather than you nad union them
select ID, Score
from (select U.ID, U.Score
      from users as U
      where U.ID <> @ID and
            U.Score < @Score
      order by U.Score desc limit 5) as P
union all
select U.ID, U.Score
from users U
where U.ID = @ID
union all
select *
from (select U.ID, U.Score
      from users as U
      where U.ID <> @ID and
            U.Score > @Score
      order by U.Score limit 5) as A
order by Score;
```

src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796636/598424